# Problem inserting new line between strange html characters in html file - UTF-8

Tags: text-processing, sed, character-encoding

I use the following command to insert new lines between characters in a text file in order to generate a single column of characters:

```sh
sed 's/./&\n/g' file.txt
```

This works for characters within ASCII; for example, from:

```
123
```

to:

```
1

2

3
```

I cannot get anything to work with multibyte characters such as `Õöþùüê¡£¢¥Ÿ£€Ÿ£¡œãòáç¢œáòá`, which appear on web pages that I download as HTML.

Any suggestions?

This is part of a solution I'm working on for another question I posted - I'm ultimately trying to generate a script to convert these characters to English- but I need to get each character on its own line.

Comment: By "funny", I assume you mean "anything that has a multi-byte UTF-8 representation"?  It looks like your sed is assuming each byte represents one character - is it operating with a non-UTF-8 locale?  (To check, use `locale charmap` in the same shell process as the `sed` command).

Comment: Alternatively, the file might be in a unibyte encoding such as ISO-8859-1, in which case a mismatch between that and a UTF-8 sed could also cause problems.  You might want to use `od` (perhaps with `-t x1c`) to examine the problematic characters closely.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions?

First of all, this works fine for me:

```
echo "Õöþùüê¡£¢" | sed 's/./&\n/g'
Õ
ö
þ
ù
ü
ê
¡
£
¢
```

Given this `locale`:

```
locale
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My guess is that your `locale` is **not** UTF-8. Try to set your `locale` to UTF-8 and try again.

Comment: Well,   echo "Õöþùüê¡£¢" | sed 's/./&\n/g'    WORKS...

Comment: My locale is UTF-8

Comment: I solved the problem while attempting to edit my post and give you some more information.  I opened the text file, selected all the lines of text and then pasted the text into another text file and VOILA! I can now dump the original text file to a single column of data - go figure.